# Addressing the cylinders of a Hard Drive

Tags: hardware, hard-drive, pata

I want to address the cylinders of a Hard Drive but I can't find a good manual of the pinout of the IDE interface. Anyone knows how to do that?

I don't want to read/write anything in the disk, just move the arm through the cylinders. And I want to do that by connecting some wires on the interface and sending some signals using a microcontroller.

Comment: So you want to simple move the head? Realize that the hard drive adds a layer of abstraction between how Parallel ATA (i.e. IDE) is accessed, and how the hard drive physically accesses the data. There is no interface accessbile way of moving the head directly, AFAIK.

Comment: Well even thought there's a layer of abstraction this does not mean is not possible to move the head, this is what the seek command do. Also a read operation can move the read, and the data read just discarded, so this is not true. If what you want is controlling the head with just an analog signal, then reformulate your question.

Comment: Are you a brazilian, Diego? I can try to explain better in Portuguese

Comment: @stdio.h should I mark your comment? Part of your question *I don't want to read/write anything in the disk, just move the arm through the cylinders. And I want to do that by connecting some wires on the interface and sending some signals using a microcontroller.* Use the seek command on the IDE interface, it will just move the head! What is not clear to you?

Answer (score 1):

The **seek command only moves the head**, but is not supported by more recently hard disk drivers, anyway maybe its worth trying.

Anyway **if you can tolerate a read operation** for example, you can calculate the position of the head by the track and sector. You can use a **no retry read** so if the read operation fails there's no retry.

[image: CHS of HD]

In fact, just calculating the track may be sufficient.

More information on the commands and the interface can be found for example [in this link](https://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/wesley.html).